# Touch Release method in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to capture the `TouchRelease` event in Android. I have seen that `event.getAction()` returns the action type. But inside `onTouchEvent` it always gives the action `ACTION_DOWN`.
Do you know how to capture the touch release event.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  Log.d(TAG,""+event.getAction());
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use `ACTION_UP`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP

```
View view = new View();

view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Consider evaluating also `ACTION_CANCEL`

Comment: i saw that there is some thing called ACTION_UP. But from the above given method it never triggers with ACTION_UP state. Do you know any other method to get that?

Comment: `ACTION_UP` is the right `MotionEvent`. Maybe the event is consumed by some other view?

Comment: @dinesh707 In your `onTouchEvent` overridden method, simply return `true` instead of `super.onTouchEvent` and then you will get the rest of the events.

Comment: @Aleadam: I think a return statement ist missing... ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG,""+event.getAction());
        return true; // Required for recieving subsequent events (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with class `SurfaceView`. Here's how I fixed it: After enabling your view's long clickable property(through setLongClickable(true)), it should works.

Comment: Cool saved me from trouble !

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // release
            return false;
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // pressed
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```