# How to detect when a touch has been released?

Tags: android, touch, libgdx, touch-event

I'm trying to find a way to detect when a touch point has been released using `gdx.input` as part of libgdx. I know about the Android way of determining when a touch point is released as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765904/touch-release-method-in-android) but I'm looking for a libgdx specific way of doing this.

How can I detect when a touch has been released?  I could not find a method that does this in `gdx.input`.

Comment: many suggestions about what I have tried.. Alot of stuff thats aint working.. I'm just looking for something like "gdx.input.isReleased"

Comment: Well to avoid suggesting things that you have already tried, please post some of the things that you have tried.  We're not opposed to helping here but we do ask that you at least share what you have tried first.

Comment: Yes, and I'm thankful for that! But I have deleted everything I tried. But I tried to impelemts a Listener, somehow make the released event be the opposite to the touchevent..

Im terrible sorry for my bad english, not all of us live in the US

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765904/touch-release-method-in-android

Comment: I know what MotionEvent is, but how do I use it in libgdx then?

Comment: @thomas.cloud I wouldn't say this is an exact duplicate as he's looking for a way to get touch events in libgdx. http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/

Comment: @MCeley, oh, okay thanks.  I hadn't heard of gdx before, guess I should have read his question better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the libgdx wiki, you must implement the `InputProcessor` interface.  In the interface there is a function called `touchUp` that should be called when touches are released.

You can read all about touch input with libgdx here: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent

There is a fairly simple example on the wiki.  Here is the implemented interface:

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped (char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false; /* This should be what you're looking for. */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchMoved (int x, int y) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled (int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to set your class as a listener:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

Comment: There we go! Thank you sir!

Comment: I suggest bookmarking the wiki in case you have any problems in the future.  It's a great place to start for most issues.  http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6