# Application Close Using Combination of Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement where I need to close my opened application using combination of keys.
Like when user will open my application and user will press twice combination of Power button and Option then application will close. Anyone can suggest me how it is possible or not?
Thanks  .

Answer (score 0):

You can `setOnTouchListener()` on each of the buttons that must be combined and use some boolean variables to control which buttons are pressed at a given time, then `finish()` your application when appropriate. See [Touch Release method in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765904/touch-release-method-in-android) for an example (which needs a little fix BTW: `onTouch()` must return true when the event has been consumed, false otherwise).

For the Power button you can override your activity's `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()` methods. There is a key code for the Power button at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: Hi Piovezan touch listener is fine but the problem is how we can override power button as we need it ? As we will use Power Button with Option Menu button to close the app.Thanks . .

Comment: I see. Then you can override onKeyDown() and onKeyUp() from your activity. There is a key code for the Power button at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html I have updated my answer accordingly.