# How to check that touch release in android?

Tags: android

I have 6 ImageView and what I need is :

If I touch on the screen First Image will show and then If I touch second time than 2nd Image will show and so on.

I did this work for make it happen but I could not find the release of the Touch. please help me to sort this problem

Code is this :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     touch_x = (int)event.getX();
     touch_y = (int)event.getY();

    // Log.e("", touch_x + "  "+ touch_y);

     if(i==0){
         layout_im1 = new LayoutParams(80, 80);
         layout_im1.setMargins(touch_x-50, touch_y-160, 0, 0);
         im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         im1.setLayoutParams(layout_im1);
                     i=1;
     }


     if(i==1){
         layout_im1 = new LayoutParams(80, 80);
         layout_im1.setMargins(touch_x-50, touch_y-160, 0, 0);
         im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         im1.setLayoutParams(layout_im1);
         i=2;
     }

     if(i==2){
         layout_im1 = new LayoutParams(80, 80);
         layout_im1.setMargins(touch_x-50, touch_y-160, 0, 0);
         im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         im1.setLayoutParams(layout_im1);
         i=3;
     }

     if(i==3){
         layout_im1 = new LayoutParams(80, 80);
         layout_im1.setMargins(touch_x-50, touch_y-160, 0, 0);
         im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         im1.setLayoutParams(layout_im1);
         i=4;
     }

     if(i==5){
         layout_im1 = new LayoutParams(80, 80);
         layout_im1.setMargins(touch_x-50, touch_y-160, 0, 0);
         im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         im1.setLayoutParams(layout_im1);
         i=6;
     }

     if(i==6){
         layout_im1 = new LayoutParams(80, 80);
         layout_im1.setMargins(touch_x-50, touch_y-160, 0, 0);
         im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         im1.setLayoutParams(layout_im1);
         i=0;
     }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: check here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765904/touch-release-method-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try get the Action from your event as shown [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765904/touch-release-method-in-android)

```
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
    }
```

Comment: If I touch and move the touch on the screen up/down etc .... than it will create the problem