# How to get the touchUP or release event from a layout on Android with Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, click, xamarin

I really searched for this but i can't find anything that helps me.
I have a Layout that has a .click event, but i need that when my finger is down on it to it's background to get darker and when i release it gets to normal again.

I found this:

[Touch Release method in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765904/touch-release-method-in-android)

But i can't make it work.

Does anyone knows if there's a way to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a listener:

```
 _myButton.SetOnTouchListener(this);
```

Add `View.IOnTouchListener` to your activity

```
public class YourActivity : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
```

Implement the listener

```
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
   {
       switch (e.Action)
       {
           case MotionEventActions.Down:
               _viewX = e.GetX();
               break;
           case MotionEventActions.Move:
               var left = (int) (e.RawX - _viewX);
               var right = (int) (left + v.Width);
               v.Layout(left, v.Top, right, v.Bottom);
               break;
       }
       return true;
   }
```

full tutorial here:
http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/

Comment: Do i need all this stuff to do the click down of a button on a layout?
On ios i can just use something.TouchUpInside or TouchDown...
There's not a simplest way for me to do that? Even if i need to use buttons and not layouts